# Performing a Segue when app enters background

Tags: objective-c, ios7, segue

I have a UIViewController that downloads multiple files if they are updated via AFHTTPOperation and an OperationQueue. If for some reason a user pushes the power button and the app goes into the background while downloading these files, I want to segue back or unwind to the previous screen. Before doing this, I am currently canceling all current operations in the download queue.

Downloads UIViewController

```
- (void)didEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([_downloadsQueue operationCount] > 0) {
        [_downloadsQueue cancelAllOperations];
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToLogin" sender:self];
}
```

Login UIViewController

```
- (IBAction)unwindToLogin:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    _passwordTextField.text = @"";
    _userNameTextField.text = @"";
    _files = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Currently, upon entering back into the app I see the downloads screen briefly before I see the login screen. Is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Comment: Does it happen if you turn off animations for that segue?

Comment: I am not sure how to turn off the animations for a unwind segue. I'll post the code for my segue above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pop back to another view, you can work directly with the navigation controller. This will work if your nib is embedded in a navigation controller. If your login view is the root view controller, you can use the following command:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

If it isn't the root, but just another view on the navigation stack then you can call this method:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
```